# Local reference jquery script in nanohttpd (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-studio, nanohttpd

I'm working around a web service using nanohttpd. I've following files in assets folder (Android Studio):

[image]

All works properly including the direct reference to JQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "></script>
```

But actually, I will not have Internet connection when I will use the server, so I need the local reference to assets folder.

I tried the simple way but doesn't work:

```
<script src="jquery_1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

I've seen other similiar question ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632029/android-nanohttpd-and-local-jquery-reference)) but I can't understand the answer :(.

Can you help me with Jquery Script reference?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What do you not understand about the linked answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use getResources().getAssets() code to access file from assets folder. For example:

```
private Response getFromAssets(String filename) {
    InputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = this.getResources().getAssets().open(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new Response(Response.Status.OK, "text/plain", "Internal Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return new Response(Response.Status.OK, /*MIME-type*/ "application/javascript", fis);
}
```